# Bottom navigation bar stop a fragment running when another one is opened

Tags: java, android

So I have no idea how to do this and even where to start, so if someone would be patient enough to explain how to do this I would be appreciated.
I already looked up on google but what I found was too difficult to understand ( and I am pretty sure that it can be done way more easily.

I have 4 fragments (4 tabs on a bottom navigation bar) and I want to have only 1 running at the time.
Now, I am pretty sure that I should use FragmentManager but I don't really know how to start to implement in my program.

Do I have to write all the FragmentTransaction code in the mainActivity? and after that how to keep goin? Is there a example code by any chance?

Disclaimer: I am a total noob in the android studio environment and I am also a student and I almost do everything as a school project.

Comment: Not being mean, Stack overflow is not to teach you to code, its to help with coding problems etc. so I suggest go google tutorials and try. I know some of the Tutorials looks difficult and intimidating, But you won;t learn unless you go out and do it

Comment: I am working on this for weeks now, so believe me, the last thing I do is to ask for help. (the deadline for the project is thje 6th of November) I was trying to figure out stuff, but I couldn't find anythng useful on google.

Comment: Viveks answer is the one to go with

Comment: otherwise you dont have to use fragments you can just use activities and us intents to switch between the activies

Answer (score 3):

You Can try this in your code. On the  onNavigationItemSelected

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                fragment = new DashboardFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                fragment = new NotificationsFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_profile:
                fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                break;
        }

        return loadFragment(fragment);
    }

    private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        //switching fragment
        if (fragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I hope this can help You!

Thank You.